# Incorrect variable information sent in PHP sessions

Tags: php, session-variables

Here is what I currently have:

```
PHP

$var1=$_GET['some_val1']
$var2=$_GET['some_val2']

$_SESSION["x"]=$var1;
$_SESSION["y"]=$var2;

header("Refresh: 180; http://some_ip/some_page.php");
```

This works well in a single user setting.

However If I have multiple users sending values simultaneously. The values sent by user2 are used for both user 1 and user 2 after redirection.

I am not sure what exactly causing the problem and hence framing is a little vague. I will explain with an example:

```
**User 1**

$var1=$_GET['some_val1'] << hello
$var2=$_GET['some_val2'] << world

echo $var1, $var2 
hello world  << Correct
**User 2**

$var1=$_GET['some_val1'] << HI
$var2=$_GET['some_val2'] << ALL

echo $var1, $var2 
HI ALL  << Correct

**on some_page.php**

**USER 1**

echo $var1, $var2
HI ALL << incorrect 

**User 2**
echo $var1, $var2
HI ALL << correct
```

Why are the values not correctly sent across sessions
How does PHP handle multiple users at once ?

Comment: `http://some_ip` :: are all these pages on the same domain?

Comment: yes. On the same IP. Just different pages

Comment: I hope you have an `exit;` call after your header(s), too

Comment: Session variable assignments do not cross over from one session to another. Sessions aren't the real problem here, it's some other implementation detail.

Comment: How do you define "different users"; are they different tabs on the same browser? different browsers on the same machine? Completely different devices?

Comment: have you set up `session_start()`? I think it would help us help you if you can show more of your *actual* code.

Comment: Your question needs some improvements. Please share the code that can be used by the community to reproduce your problem. The only reason what I can guess with the limited details is that you are using the same SESSION variables that overwrite the previous value. It is better to have a dynamic SESSION variable name instead.

Comment: @Martin Yes i am emulating different users by multiple tabs on my browser. and I think here is the problem becuase chrome will remember sessions and replace them for me ? Is that the case ?

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi yes there is only onr pHP page. So for each user the name of the variables is the same

Comment: SESSIONS are stored until either unset or browser is exited. So if multiple users use the same browser without restarting it and you are not unsetting the SESSION variable once the required process is completed, you will face this issue. It is always a good practice to UNSET the SESSIONS once the process is completed.

Comment: yes i tried with different PC's and the i am not facing the problem now. Thank you

Comment: Sessions are stored in the browser, not the tab. If you want to test multiple users, either use different browsers (i.e. one in chrome, one in firefox), or test one in Privacy mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Comments:

> How do you define "different users"; are they different tabs on the same browser? different browsers on the same machine? Completely different devices?

---

> Yes i am emulating different users by multiple tabs on my browser.

---

> Sessions are stored in the browser, not the tab. If you want to test multiple users, either use different browsers (i.e. one in Chrome, one in Firefox), or test one in Privacy mode.

-- aynber

**This** is the cause of your inconsistency issues. In Addition:

> SESSIONS are stored until either unset or browser is exited. So if multiple users use the same browser without restarting it and you are not unsetting the SESSION variable once the required process is completed, you will face this issue. It is always a good practice to UNSET the SESSIONS once the process is completed.

--  Mohammed Akhtar Zuberi